# Howto connect nexus 7 to ADT in vmware Windows guest

Tags: android, vmware, adt, nexus-7

I have successfully setup Android Developer Tools (the latest eclipse based package) on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 PC and connected a Nexus 7 and ran a hello world example using phonegap.

Now I want to do the same but using Vmware Workstation 9 to run a Win 7 guest with ADT. I am able to set up the environment and an connect the Nexus 7 as a removable device in the vmware win 7 guest, but the Nexus 7 does not appear in ADT in the list of real devices attached. I have installed the google usb drivers as required in the ADT software manager.

I have basically followed the same steps as I did in the standalone Win 7 pc which works. But it seems that running win 7 as a VMware guest is causing some problem.

All my environments are 64 bit OS.